# Python Selenium: Can't find the login element of costar.com

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, element

I am getting very frustrated trying to login to costar.com with python and selenium.  I have tried it on the chrome browser and firefox browser, but can't figure out the correct code.

I have logged into other websites, but cannot figure out how to input text into the login boxes for this site.

Here's what I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/Gus Gabel/Anaconda/chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("http://www.costar.com")

browser.maximize_window()

#the username and password boxes are hidden until you press the login button on the home page
login = browser.find_element_by_id("loginLink")
login.click()

#now that the username and password boxes are available, I've tried finding the elements by class_name, xpath, (BY.NAME), id, etc and nothing has worked
#here are a few codes that haven't worked and the errors associated
user = browser.find_element_by_id('username')
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element

user = browser.find_element_by_class_name('usernameNew')
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element

#when i try to use the above code with "elements" instead of "element", no error message pops up.
user = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('usernameNew')

#but then whey i try to choose which element by doing this
user = browser.find_element_by_class_name('usernameNew')[0]
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element
```

How is it possible that there can be a list of elements, but yet not have an initial element?

If anyone can figure out how to input text into the username and password text boxes of costar.com, I will be greatly appreciative.  I can't figure this out for the life of me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enter text into an input box with Selenium (e.g, your user name into the username field), use the [`send_keys`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=send_keys#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.send_keys) method of the element:

```
input_element.send_keys('some_text_string')
```

You can also try Selenium's [`action_chains`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html) module, as in the following code (untested), to get past the roadblock from @dm295's answer:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import action_chains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://www.costar.com")

action = action_chains.ActionChains(driver)

login = driver.find_element_by_class_name("login-icon")
login.click()

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('custlogin'))

username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')

action.move_to_element(username).perform()

username.send_keys('Gus Gabel')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I am new to selenium and python and had never needed to change frames before.  This solved my problem!! However, I have a new issue. Once I put in my username and password, an invisible frame pops us and I can't figure out how to click OK on it.  If you want to see what I'm talking about, look at the source code and ctrl-f "invisible" or "certificate".  Do you know how I might navigate this? Tried using Keys.RETURN and searching for the frame. Neither worked :/

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:
(a) you have to wait until the page is loaded (or at least the part of the page that you are interested in)
(b) only maximized browser window works for me (depends on device/resolution)
(c) you are trying to click the wrong element

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://www.costar.com")

try:
    # wait 15 seconds till the login link is present
    login = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "login-icon"))
    )

    login.click()

    # just sleep 5 seconds to show that the login link was clicked
    time.sleep(5)

    # do other stuff (probably fill in username and password) ...

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Read the documentation regards [waiting](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html) in selenium.

**EDIT**

Manged to get one step further (`switch to iframe`), but the following code raises

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message:
>   Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://www.costar.com")

try:
    login = driver.find_element_by_class_name("login-icon")
    login.click()

    # switch to the custlogin iframe
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('custlogin'))

    username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')

    # this will raise:
    # selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message:
    # Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
    username.send_keys('username')

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: I should have been more specific.  I can get the username and password boxes to pop up, but I cannot input anything into them. Your method allows me to get to where I was before, but I still don't know how to enter my username and password into the boxes.

Comment: Basically, I need help where you write "# do other stuff (probably fill in username and password)"

Comment: @Gus Gabel - edited: still not working but at least one step closer

Comment: So, it isn't possible to do because it's not visible?

Comment: yes - if you somehow can update visibility (`username.click()` is not working) than you can insert actual username